# How can i retrieve an attribute of an object stored in a ListBox

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2010, I have created a class "Item", and I have populated a ListBox with multiple instances of this class. Now for each object in the ListBox I want to call a get method, and retrieve an attribute.

This is what i have tried :

```
Public Function calTotal() As Decimal

    For x = 0 To (ItemObjects.Items.Count - 1)
        Total = ItemObjects.Items(x). 'Right after i press dot, it should show me all the class methods
    Next

    Return 0
End Function
```

But it doesn't let me see them. Mind you, all methods in the class are Public, also even when i make the attributes them selves Public as well, Still.

Second Question : I am using the ListBox cause in a way it kinda works like an arrayList, LinkedList, Vector but i don't know how to use or create these data structures in VB.NET

Comment: The Items collection stores everything as `Object`, so all your class's properties and methods wont show.  Cast it back to your type (CType)

Comment: @Plutonix : Wouldn't `DirectCast` be both better and faster?

Comment: Ahhh damn it :) i just remembered generic types and figured it out. I have created `Public myList As List(Of MyType) = New List(Of MyType)`. Don't know what was i thinking, anyway Thanks guys :)